# large difference in execution speed during file read

Tags: java, file

Can anyone explain why is this happening? The filesize is up to 2MB. It takes less than 2 seconds for the code to execute.

```
try {
    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
        System.out.println(line);
}
catch(Exception e)
{           
}
```

But when I change the code to:

```
String temp = "";
try {
    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
        temp =temp + line;
}
catch(Exception e)
{
}
```

I understand it would take comparatively more time but it takes the massive time of 470 seconds. Why this difference?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1126388/slow-string-concatenation-over-large-input

Comment: String concatenation is slow.

Comment: `StringBuilder` may be an option here !

Comment: You are changing an O(N) algo into an O(N^2) algo, so why wouldn't it make a big difference for larger files.

Comment: Every time you do the `+` concatenation you create a new String object.  Even if the object creation itself is not too bad, you leave behind an enormous amount of garbage that must be collected frequently.  This sort of scenario is frequently the primary cause for poor GC behavior.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> ```
> temp =temp + line;
> ```

Is concatenation of a string as-is. The concatenation requires that a new string object is created and possibly interned, taking a lot of time. Instead, think about using a StringBuilder in most cases or StringBuffer where synchronization is needed.

Create it once with

```
StringBuilder sb=new StringBuilder()
```

and append with:

```
sb.append(line);
```

You can then grab the data with `sb.toString()`.

Comment: Prefer `StringBuilder` over `StringBuffer` in most circumstances.

Comment: @hexafraction [Yes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html)

Comment: Yes, `StringBuffer` is synchronized whereas `StringBuilder` is not.

Comment: You can initialize the size of the buffer when you 'new' it. That's handy if you can use the file size to estimate the number of characters. (Since the newlines are going away.)

Comment: @LeeMeador Does that give a tangible performance benefit? It seems that there would be less overhead but I'm not fully sure.

Comment: If you go read the benchmarks that @jh314 links to, you will see some effect. Is it major? Dunno. But I though someone should mention it. Especially when you can estimate from the file.

Answer (score 1):

In Java, strings are immutable.  So this statement:

```
temp =temp + line;
```

creates a new string object for each line in your file, which slows things down.  Some better alternatives include [StringBuilder](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html) and [StringBuffer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuffer.html)

You can find some benchmarks [here](http://kaioa.com/node/59) that compare the speed of these 3 ways of concatenating strings.